# Transferring method result variables into another class

Tags: java, android

I have a method which returns the latitude and longitude of the GPS current location. I would like to store these values inside public variables so that i can access them from another static class which its job is to send an SMS with the latitude and longitude as message.

I have this code in the Main Activity:

```
location.getLatitude();
location.getLongitude();

strLongitude = location.convert(location.getLongitude(), location.FORMAT_DEGREES);
strLatitude = location.convert(location.getLatitude(), location.FORMAT_DEGREES);
```

In the other static class:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
// Send a text based SMS
smsManager.sendTextMessage(senderNum,null,"Latitude and Longitude", null,null);
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your code. 6 lines of code is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

And what prevents you from declaring:

```
public static String longitudeAsString
```

in your Main activity; and assigning the result of your method calls to such a field? So that you just do

```
String longitudeFromMain = YourMainActivity.longitudeAsString()
```

I guess: your lack of knowledge. So the **real** answer here is: you have to **learn** the java basics **first**. Like: going [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and working trough *most* of that content.

Finally: actually you should **avoid** to use static fields to transport information. Using **static** is often bad practice; and having public fields that can be read **and** written are bad practice, too.

Comment: Or return the Location object. Put it into string format later

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f4440b36aa33a16173af5e40b9f0468c
Ran this code but it would still show null.

I debugged the variables in the main activity and theyre string so what is wrong? https://gyazo.com/35791dc3d705b05f15c9864c38f52fc5

Comment: @TomSmith Please spend some time at the [help] - you put your [mcve] in your **question** - you **never** link to external sites for your code.

Comment: You see, there could be a **timing** issue. It is absolutely **impossible** to understand what your code is doing ... without seeing all relevant parts of your code!